# GaussianMixture equivalents for GMM functions (sklearn python)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deprecated, gmm

I'm working on a code received from a collaborator and it contains two functions from the deprecated GMM class in sklearn:
distribute_covar_matrix_to_match_covariance_type
log_multivariate_normal_density

Since I'm not that familiar with the math behind it, I'm having a hard time finding the equivalent functions in the new GaussianMixture class. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The section of the code that calls the functions is below:

```
for x in models:
  bics=[]
  gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=x, n_iter=100000, n_init=5, covariance_type='full')
  gmm.fit(np.array(s))
  bic.append(gmm.bic(np.array(s)))
return bic.index(min(bic))+2
```

Comment: Please mention both the scikit versions, along with sample codes as to what you are doing?

Comment: I think I have 19.1 installed
(updated code above)

Comment: The newer version also has a [`bic()` method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.bic), which I think will work without worrying too much about the internal workings of the library.

Comment: Ooooh thank you so much!

So should I just change mixture and GMM for GaussianMixture? (and I guess n_iter to max_iter?)

for x in models:
  bics=[]
  gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=x, max_iter=100000, n_init=5, covariance_type='full')
  gmm.fit(np.array(s))
  bic.append(gmm.bic(np.array(s)))
return bic.index(min(bic))+2

Comment: Wait, I got it :D Thank you so much!

for x in models:
  bics=[]
  gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=x, max_iter=100000, n_init=5, covariance_type='full')
  gmm.fit(np.array(s))
  bic.append(gmm.bic(np.array(s)))
return bic.index(min(bic))+2

Comment: Rather than edit the question with the answer, you should post it as an answer to your own question and then accept it after two days if no better answer is posted by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround: Just substitute "GMM" by "GaussianMixture" and "n_iter" by "max_itern":

```
for x in models:
  bics=[]
  gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=x, max_iter=100000, n_init=5, covariance_type='full')
  gmm.fit(np.array(s))
  bic.append(gmm.bic(np.array(s)))
return bic.index(min(bic))+2
```

Thank you @Vivek Kumar